# Why the current in X ray tube is in milli amps

Tags: current, high-voltage, tube

If we see a X ray generating tube the voltage applying to tube is in kV, but the tube current is in milliamps. Why this current is in mAs not in amps?

Comment: Because one ampere is a lot of charges per second.

Comment: it's enough for a strong and heavy boxer to hit once to win a match; a weak boxer with good technique will have to throw many punches instead. $$P = I * V$$

Comment: KiloVolt = 10³ and milliamp = -10³ so (kv times ma) would be power. As the powers of 10 cancel out.

Comment: You asked below about how much voltage is required to accelerate electrons, the answer is *any voltage* will accelerate electrons. E.g. a 10kV X-Ray tube needs 10'000V to accelerate electrons to 10keV, a 100keV X-ray tube needs 100'000V, but even a millivolt will accelerate an electron, it's just that a millivolt will accelerate an electron to ~6km/hr as opposed to 19% light speed for an electron passing through a 100kV gradient. The current relates to *how many* electrons you wish to accelerate, with 1A being around 6.2*10^18 electrons *every second*

Comment: @Sam: Yes of course a millivolt can accelerate an electron, but here the thing is at how many volts the X ray is produced. That means the huge crowd of electrons at the cathode filament should accelerate towards rotating anode and dash it. This is possible only if we apply a voltage in kV. My question is in CT what is the range of voltage using, and for how many volts the Xrays can penetrate in to bones also

Comment: There isn't an exact answer to 'what voltage you need to produce x-rays' as the definition is a little fuzzy, technically anything of higher photon energy than UV is an x-ray. A 100eV photon is an x-ray photon and needs only 100V, a 10MeV photon is *still* considered an x-ray photon in some contexts as there isn't a good consensus on where x-rays end and gamma rays start. If you want a more accurate answer I'd recommend perhaps asking on Health SE, you might get an answer from an actual CT technician there. As for the penetrative power of X-rays, perhaps Physics SE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An X-ray tube might require 100kV. A current of only 1A would be 100kW, which is a fairly large amount of power even for a water cooled tube with rotating target.

The efficiency using a tungsten target would be less than 1%, so most of the power goes into heat.

There's no need to produce more X-rays than required, however CT scans may require something of the order of a 100kW power input. They also can expose the patient to a relatively large amount of radiation.

Along similar lines, a particle accelerator beam of just a few tens of nA can carry a great deal of power if the particles are energetic enough (say hundreds of MeV).

Comment: But as per you can we give 10kV with an few amps like 10Amps? if so it also has same 10kV x 10amps =100kW

Comment: @AshokKumar: To get some xrays, you need accelerated electrons, and their acceleration is done by the voltage, so if the voltage is low, there is no xrays

Comment: ok thank you i understood. So what is the minimum kV we need to accelerate the electrons

Comment: I mean in normal CT applications what is the amount of minimum kV using

Comment: "CT scans may require something of the order of a 100kW power input" ... hopefully with an extremely small duty cycle, 100kW sounds like a way to fully cook instead of diagnose the patient ;)

Comment: The voltage required depends on what Xray energy you need, higher energy Xrays penetrate better then low energy ones, and the upper limit on the per photon energy is clearly given by the energy of the electron when it decelerates in the collision with the target. Note that there is a difference between the energy of the Xray photons (Depends on voltage) and the intensity of the beam (Depends on current), independent control is possibly by varying the cathode temperature and thus emission.

Comment: @rackandboneman The X-ray output is much less than the heating- it's not a microwave oven, but it's still enough radiation damage that you shouldn't have it done very often- the equivalent of a several years of background radiation in one go.

Comment: @AshokKumar Diagnostic x-rays are typically generated by voltages between 30kV and 150kV.  Currents vary from microamperes to tens of milliamperes.  Industrial systems (and CT scanners) have higher currents or voltages.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany it is known that the input power is equal to the output power then how is such a large input power is provided by the 220VAC? I mean 100kW/310=322A. Then practically not possible, then how does it work??

Comment: @kam1212 The HV power supply would be wired into 3-phase 480VAC or similar input voltage. Current would be around 120A for 100kW. That's for CT not for your dental X-ray.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Actually I was confused as I have seen a load resistor of 10ohm 100W at the AC side before rectification in the X-ray generator but why isn't it getting damaged makes me confused if the load is even 32kW. Wount the input current damage it?

Answer (score 1):

Power is voltage multiplied with current. As you say, voltage is in the order of a few kV. If the current was in the amps range, you'd need to supply thousands of watts. Most of that power goes into heating the tube, rather than actually producing x-rays.